# Редактирование загрузочного ядра Linux X96MAX

Tags: android, linux, ядро, reverse

Я пытаюсь изменить пару байт в ядре linux приставки X96Max+. Из прошивки вытащил файл boot.PARTITION

С помощью утилиты binwalk получил следующую информацию:

```
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             Android bootimg, kernel size: 9944632 bytes, kernel addr: 0x1080000, ramdisk size: 0 bytes, ramdisk addr: 0x1000000, product name: ""
2048          0x800           uImage header, header size: 64 bytes, header CRC: 0x9190F11E, created: 2022-04-15 10:28:54, image size: 9944568 bytes, Data Address: 0x108000, Entry Point: 0x108000, data CRC: 0x93A4A015, OS: Linux, CPU: ARM, image type: OS Kernel Image, compression type: none, image name: "Linux-4.9.113"
2112          0x840           Linux kernel ARM boot executable zImage (little-endian)
30652         0x77BC          gzip compressed data, maximum compression, from Unix, last modified: 1970-01-01 00:00:00 (null date)
9947136       0x97C800        gzip compressed data, from Unix, last modified: 1970-01-01 00:00:00 (null date)
```

Архив с ядром linux находится по смещению 0x77BC, после распаковки, изменения и обратной упаковки архив стал на 10 байт меньше оригинала. В заголовке uImage обновил CRC заголовка и данных, но образ все равно не загружается. При отладке висит на сообщении "Starting kernel".  Может ли кто подсказать что я делаю не так?

Comment: Наверное после модификации какие-нибудь контрольные суммы (типа `header CRC: 0x9190F11E`) изменились и один из цепочки загрузчиков отказался правильно отработать